# HttpClient can't get response from server

Tags: java, sockets, httpclient

This problem has blocked our whole team half a day!

We use apache httpclient 4.3.x to post and get data from an storage server which provides http api. In order to improve performance, we used `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`:

```
public HttpClient createHttpClient() {
    Registry registry = RegistryBuilder.create()....build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(50);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
       .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
       .build();
    return httpClient;
}
```

Then we hold an instance of the httpClient in our program, reuse it with every http request:

Global httpClient:

```
HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
```

Post some data:

```
HttpPost httpPut = new HttpPost("...");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);

// Notice we get the response content here!
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(content);

httpPut.releaseConnection();
response.close();
```

Then get:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("...");

// Blocked at this line !!!!
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(content);

httpPut.releaseConnection();
response.close();
```

Please notice the line: `// Blocked at this line !!!!`

The program has blocked at that line and never go to next line. In debugging mode, I can see it has been blocked at:

```
SocketInputStream.socketRead0()
```

I've searched for a lot of questions and documents, but no lucky.

---

My colleage just fix it by setting `NoConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE`:

```
 HttpClients.custom()
       .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
       // Following line fixed the problem, but why?
       .setConnectionReuseStrategy(NoConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE)
       .build();
```

Now it doens't blocked, but why?

What does "reuse connection" mean? And is there performance issue by using `NoConnectionReuseStrategy`?

Thank you, guys~

Answer (score 4):

I tried to reproduce the blocking http-get (also as an exercise for myself) but even without closing responses I could not get it to block. The ONLY time I managed to make the http-get block is by doing a `response.getEntity().getContent()` without reading from the returned `InputStream` and without closing the returned `InputStream`.
For my tests I used Tomcat 7.0.47 with two very simple servlets (one responding "OK" to a get, the other echoing a post) as a server. The client started 50 threads with each thread performing 30 alternating http-get and http-post request (total of 1500 requests). The client did not use the `RegistryBuilder`, instead the default one is used (created by the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` itself).

About the `NoConnectionReuseStrategy`: by default (HttpClient created with `HttpClients.createDefault()`, I used `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1`) a connection pool is used with a maximum of 2 connections to 1 server. E.g. even if 5 threads are doing all kinds of requests at the same time to 1 server, the connection pool opens only 2 connections, re-uses them for all requests and ensures that 1 connection is used by 1 thread at any given time. This can have a very positive impact on client performance and significantly reduces load on the server. The only thing you must make sure is to call `response.close()` in a finally-block (this ensures the connection is returned to the connection pool). By using the `NoConnectionReuseStrategy` you basically disable the connection pool: for each request a new connection will be created. I recommend you enable debug-logging for category `org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`, it is very informative.

A note about `httpPut.releaseConnection()`: this does not actually release a connection, it only ensures that you can re-use the "httpPut" object in a next request (see the [apidocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html#releaseConnection%28%29), follow the shown link). Also note that in your code for the "httpGet", you call `releaseConnection()` on "httpPut" instead of "httpGet".

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem just a while back. In case someone else comes across this problem, this post might be useful.

I am using a Java Servlet to service my requests. When I wrote to the response stream using the PrintWriter instance my client blocked. Tried writing to the OutputStream directly`response.getOutputStream.write("myresponse")` and it worked.